# Specify which libstdc++ to use

Tags: gcc, libraries, c++, compiler

I want to make use of a more recent GCC version. Therefore, I compiled GCC 10 and installed it into a non-standard directory `/software/gcc10/`. So far so good.

However, I am faced with problems when I actually want to use this new version of GCC. I modified my `PATH` variable to include `/software/gcc10/bin/` such that `gcc --version` now confirms that the system finds my new GCC 10 compiler (instead of my system's GCC 8 one).

However, when I try to compile a program with this setup, I get errors about undefined references to `std::filesystem`, which should be part of GCC 10's libstdc++. My assumption here is that while I am now using a more recent compiler, the linker still wants to link against my system's libstdc++ instead of that in `/software/gcc10/lib64`.

I tried changing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the respective directory, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Inspecting the output of running `gcc` with the `-v` option, I stumbled upon the `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, which according to [gcc's docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html) is used as follows:

> The value of LIBRARY_PATH is a colon-separated list of directories, much like PATH. When configured as a native compiler, GCC tries the directories thus specified when searching for special linker files, if it cannot find them using GCC_EXEC_PREFIX. Linking using GCC also uses these directories when searching for ordinary libraries for the -l option (but directories specified with -L come first).

And indeed: Setting the `LIBRARY_PATH` variable accordingly allows me to compile my program successfully. However, it seems that this is a gcc-specific solution and I can't help but wonder whether there is a more standard way of doing this (that would e.g. also tell clang where to look for the C++ standard library to link against)?

Even better would be a solution that would cause my new GCC 10 compiler to always use the GCC 10 stdlib whilst invocation of the system's GCC 8 compiler would always link against the systems GCC 8 stdlib. Is there a way to tell a specific compiler binary that it has a specific stdlib that it should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable is pretty standard. It is known to majority of compilers.

You should also use `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and/or `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`. These two a more gcc specific (other compilers prefer `INCLUDE` without language separation).

You can also ignore the environment variables completely and specify the correct libstdc++ directly in the command line.

```
g++ main.cpp /software/gcc10/.../libstdc++.a
```

Comment: Great! That's good to know, thank you!